# how to find who is eating my memory in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a page which contain six js included,when the page run about more than 5 mins(with user's operation),the page will turn to run slowly,and from the task manager,I see the browser take more than 150M memeory,so I think there must be a variable in my js which is eating my memory no-normally,but I have no idea how to find it.

Is there any tool or any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gogle chrome can help you. Turn on Developers tools (press F12) -> Profiles and in bottom line you find "Take heap snapshot" (eye icon).

Or you can start profiling and determine, which function eat most CPU resources.

Comment: Maybe firebug can help you, but I am not sure. Firebug can profile javascript, but I cant find **view heap** function.

Comment: I agree with @hguser: Firefox extensions often take a huge amount of CPU %.

Comment: I found the memory eaten in both IE7 and firefox.